# Why does this function work on macOS and not on Windows?

Tags: python, configparser

I have a function that is reading a file with configparser and on Windows I have problems with the file encoding.

This is the function:

```
def getSetting(name,section):
    cpass = configparser.RawConfigParser()
    cpass.read('data/settings.data', encoding='UTF-8')
    

    value = 'False'

    for each_section in cpass.sections():
        for (each_key, each_val) in cpass.items(each_section):
            if each_section == section and each_key == name:
                value = each_val

    if name == 'log' and value == 'False':
        value = translations['disabilitato_first_cap']
        
    return value
```

I've tried with this, as told in a question I found on Stack Overflow itself:

```
def getSetting(name,section):
    cpass = configparser.RawConfigParser()

    with open('data/settings.data', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        cpass.read_file(f)

        value = 'False'

        for each_section in cpass.sections():
            for (each_key, each_val) in cpass.items(each_section):
                if each_section == section and each_key == name:
                    value = each_val

        if name == 'log' and value == 'False':
            value = translations['disabilitato_first_cap']
            
    return value
```

And I've tried also adding this line on top of my Python files:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

But nothing really works.

This is the function that generate the file:

```
def checkSettings(if_false_create):
    cpass = configparser.RawConfigParser()
    try:
        with open('data/settings.data', encoding="UTF-8") as f:
            cpass.read_file(f)
            return True
    except IOError:
        print(colors.wy+" "+translations['impostazioni_base_configurate'])
        if if_false_create == False:
            return False
        else:
            log = translations['disabilitato_first_cap']
            settings = configparser.RawConfigParser()
            settings.add_section("general_settings")
            settings.set("general_settings", "log", translations['disabilitato_first_cap'])
            settings.set("general_settings", "analyze_account", "doublegram_test_user")
            settings.set("general_settings", "between_autoinvite_pause", "1-3 "+translations['abbreviazione_secondi']+" ("+translations['casuale']+")")
            settings.set("general_settings", "between_invite_pause", "1-3 "+translations['abbreviazione_secondi']+" ("+translations['casuale']+")")
            setup = open("data/settings.data", "w")
            settings.write(setup)

            settings.add_section("adding_settings")
            settings.set("adding_settings", "between_autoinvite_pause", "1-3 "+translations['abbreviazione_secondi']+" ("+translations['casuale']+")")
            settings.set("adding_settings", "auto_add_at_start", translations['abilitato_first_cap'])
            settings.set("adding_settings", "if_account_out", translations['abilitato_first_cap'])
            settings.set("adding_settings", "change_account_n_requests", "20 "+translations['richieste'])
            settings.set("adding_settings", "change_account_pause", "1-5 "+translations['abbreviazione_secondi']+" ("+translations['casuale']+")")
            settings.set("adding_settings", "consecutive_error_breaker", "30 "+translations['errori'])
            settings.set("adding_settings", "start_point_members_file", translations['da_interrotto'])
            settings.set("adding_settings", "add_using", translations['user_id_opt'])
            settings.set("adding_settings", "between_adding_pause", "1-3 "+translations['abbreviazione_secondi']+" ("+translations['casuale']+")")
            settings.set("adding_settings", "casual_pause_times", "3-120 "+translations['abbreviazione_secondi']+" ("+translations['casuale']+")")
            settings.set("adding_settings", "exclude_bot", translations['abilitato_first_cap'])
            settings.set("adding_settings", "exclude_admin", translations['abilitato_first_cap'])
            settings.set("adding_settings", "photo_forcing", translations['abilitato_first_cap'])
            settings.set("adding_settings", "filter_last_seen", translations['nessuna_restrizione'])
            settings.set("adding_settings", "filter_dc", translations['nessuna_restrizione'])
            settings.set("adding_settings", "filter_phone_number", translations['disabilitato_first_cap'])
            settings.set("adding_settings", "stop_max_adding", translations['nessun_limite'])
            settings.set("adding_settings", "continuous_adding", translations['disabilitato_first_cap'])
            settings.set("adding_settings", "ca_ripet", translations['infinito'])
            settings.set("adding_settings", "ca_pause", translations['nessuna_pausa'])
            setup = open("data/settings.data", "w")
            settings.write(setup)
            
            setup.close()
            return log
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "i have problems with the file encoding"? What kind of problems? Are there any error messages?

Comment: _Is_ the file you're reading encoded in UTF8?

Comment: There is a message saying this: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte python configparser and continue with the specific character it can't decode, also if the file is empty

Comment: Yes the file is made in utf8 with configparser functions

Comment: I've updated the post with the function that create the file first

Comment: You're making us guess what the actual error is.  Please update the question to show the full error traceback message.

Comment: This line: `setup = open("data/settings.data", "w")` does not specify to write in `utf-8` encoding.

Comment: The problem is that actually i haven't got the Windows machine anymore but i will update with the exact error asap

Comment: I will test adding the encoding parameter

Comment: Windows file encoding is *not* `utf-8` by default. It's likely to be a native code page such as `cp1252`.

Comment: @AnyaShenanigans and Macos is utf-8 by deafult?

Comment: @AnyaShenanigans the problem was, as you told, that i have to save in utf8 in the previous function. If you can type your answer i will mark it as correct. Thank you so much. I'm new to this problem and actually i was thinking i solved the encoding problem a lot of time ago by placing utf8 where needed and i solved many bugs but i faced this problem just now so i was pretty sure that the saving of file was not a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the platform you're using, python behaves differently in relation to the encoding of string/binary data. In Linux, your locale will typically define what encoding the data will be processed with. When you're at a logged on desktop, you may end up with `UTF-8` default encoding, but when you run under an environment such as cron, or in docker, you end up with `ascii` encoding. On the Mac, it's almost always `UTF-8`. On Windows, you typically end up with one of it's codepages, such as `cp1252`.

The long and short of this is that *every* time you read or write data you need to specify the encoding to the open function, to ensure that we process the file appropriately. If we forget the encoding at one side, then we can be stung on the other side.

It's even got [PEP-597](https://peps.python.org/pep-0597/), to help people by introducing a warning when you forget to use an encoding. If you pass your code throught pylint and pyflakes, it will also remind you that you should use the encoding parameter.

So every:

```
open(filename)
```

that isn't binary, should almost always have an explicit `encoding=` parameter. Forgetting the parameter is *almost* always a mistake.